# sql server 2005 tsql abs doesn't like decimals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

trying to run the following statement in sql mgmt studio

```
declare @rick as decimal(13,3)
@rick = -.5
select bob = abs(@rick)
```

any ideas why this won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a Set on line 2. With that, I get the proper .5. I.e.:

```
declare @rick as decimal(13,3)
set @rick = -.5
select bob = abs(@rick)
```

Comment: There is a Set on line two, I can't see that there should be more than one?

Comment: The Set on line two is there because I added it. Will edit to be more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Stu. Missing SET is the only problem.

Comment: No. Without a SET (or SELECT, that would work as well in this case), the second line isn't a valid SQL statement -- period.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine over here, `bob = 0.500`. What error do you get?